# Is there another way to go back to the rgb image to extract the inicial countour in the registered image?

Tags: image, matlab, rgb

I already made the image registration, and now I want to apply the registered image in rgb because I need to extract the countourr. As the imregister just work with grayscale images I converted my image to grayscale,but now I can´t find the intensity value of the contour to find the contour indexes. Wat kind of algorithm does imregister applies to the image, tochange the intensity value of the pixels? Or there is another way to go back to the rgb image to extract the inicial countour in the registered image? Does anyone have any sugestion?
There is my matlab code :

```
% Algorithm for image validation
% Open the two images which will be compared
name2=input('Image name ( automated segmentation)     ','s');
img_automated=imread(name2,'png');
figure (1), imshow(img_automated), title('Image automated')
name=input('Image name ( manual segmentation)     ','s');
img_manual=imread(name,'png');
img_manual_gray=rgb2gray(img_manual);
%img_manual_gray=img_manual(:,:,3);
figure (2), imshow (img_manual),title('Image manual')
img_automated_gray=rgb2gray(img_automated);
%img_automated_gray=img_automated(:,:,3);
%img_double=im2double(img_automated_gray);
figure (3), imshow (img_automated_gray), title (' Image converted to double ');

%img_automated_gray2=rgb2gray(img_automated);
% View images side by side
figure (6), imshowpair(img_manual,img_automated_eq,'diff')
title('Images overlap')
   %% Configure parameters in imreconfig
  [optimizer,metric]=imregconfig('Multimodal');
%% Default registration
registered=imregister(img_automated_gray,img_manual_gray,'rigid',optimizer,metric);
%tform = imregtform(img_automated,img_manual,imref2d,'affine',optimizer,metric)
figure(7), imshowpair(registered, img_manual_gray,'falsecolor'); title('Default registration');
figure(8), imshowpair(registered, img_manual_gray,'montage','Scaling','independent'); title('Default registration');
figure(9), imshow(registered);

C = imfuse(registered,img_automated);
figure(21);imshow(C);

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Here%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

%%I tried this process to recover the transformation applied in the registered image,and them aplly this in the initial automated rgb image,but B isn't the same as the registered image. Any suggestions??

```
tform = imregtform(img_automated_gray,img_manual_gray,'rigid',optimizer,metric);
B = imwarp(img_automated,tform);
figure(22);imshow(B);
```

Links to the images:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/xbanupnpjaaurj5/manual.png?dl=0  (manual- rgb)
https://www.dropbox.com/s/6fkwi3xbicwzonz/registered%20image.png?dl=0

Comment: Could you narrow down your issue to minimal code?

Comment: Can you perform the registration in the reverse direction so that the image with the contour is the reference image?

Comment: No, because,I want the manual segmentation to be my reference image, not the initial rgb image with the countour, this is the image I want to register in relation to the manual segmentation ( pass to the same coordinate system). My problem is that the process of registration changes the intensity values of the registered image, and with this result I can't extract the countour of the registered image. Do you have any suggestion toobtain the countour?

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track with your use of imregtform. The missing piece is that imwarp, by default, chooses an output grid with the same resolution as the input grid with limits big enough to capture the entire output image.

In most registration cases, this is not what you want. What you want, is to specify the 'OutputView' Name/Value to specify the resolution and limits that you want in the output grid. In many registration use cases, this is the resolution/limits of the fixed image:

```
tform = imregtform(img_automated_gray,img_manual_gray,'rigid',optimizer,metric);
B = imwarp(img_automated,tform,'OutputView',imref2d(size(img_manual_gray)));
figure(22);imshow(B);
```